# Nginx Server Blocks not working

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-17.10

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and installed nginx/php7.1/mysql

Im trying to get nginx to work following this article->[How To Set Up Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

My current server block file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/flashyweb.dev/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name www.flashyweb.dev;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I've did sudo systemctl restart nginx and tried to enter flashyweb.dev, but it doesn't worked, i've got this message:

> This site can’t be reached www.flashyweb.dev’s server IP address could
>   not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Please help me, i already searched alot but cant find a solution for this.

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean`, if it still not working, check your dns setting on your router or on your domain hosting setting.

Comment: still cant get to work, how i can configure my dns setting ? have a tutorial ?

Comment: are you using a hosting service or this is just a private server?

Comment: are just local host

Comment: Change the `server_name www.flashyweb.dev;` to `server_name localhost;` to see if it is working. I'm more familiar with Debian so not quite sure Ubuntu will be the same, did you set the `192.168.xxx.xxx www.flashyweb.dev` in `/etc/hosts`? You need to match the local IP with the domain name.

Comment: Hi @flashydev could you fix the issue? I faced the similar problem and fixed it by setting primary DNS of my pc to 8.8.8.8 and secondary DNS to 9.9.9.9. But the thing is my site gives the same issue in many computers. So I think there should be a permanent solution. If you know the proper solution then please share it here. Thanks